# where can i find the version of python that is on codecademy

Tags: python

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for here, so if it isn't, I apologize, however I'm not sure where else to ask.

I've been learning python on codecademy however when I downloaded python myself it is nothing like what I've become used to. I can't for the life of me figure out where to define fucntions and I don't know where to find the console.

I would like basically the same that codecademy has with the editor / console 2-in-1 combo. Where can I find this?

FWIW I have python 3.3.5 that I downloaded from www.python.org

Thank you.

Comment: If you tell us which OS you are running, we might be able to give you better advice.

Answer (score 3):

The version used by CodeAcademy is Python 2.

Download Python 2 from here: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/

Once you are done downloading and installing it, open "IDLE (Python GUI)" and press <CTRL + N>.

This will open the python text editor. Enter your code, functions, and etc. in here.

Then press <F5> to run it.

This is what you should be seeing:

Python Shell (when you first run Python IDLE): http://gyazo.com/a3eca0fb88139c3a526b6f8fdfa6e4c0

And then when you press , you should see a blank file: http://gyazo.com/1d4426ac0e9fb49a50ea33fce881fcb6

Comment: With Python 3 <CTRL-N> gives another Python Shell.

Comment: It shouldn't be another shell. Can you take a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

As Amit pointed out, CodeAcademy is currently using Python 2.7.3. (I don't for the life of me see why that got downvoted, it's entirely relevant to the question, and "Python 2" covers an awful lot of ground.)

I can't recommend Python 3.x for working on CodeAcademy problems; the syntax and module changes from 2.x to 3.x will give you unending problems (with any luck they will update their course soon).

You can download the latest Python 2.7 (currently 2.7.6) from Python.org (https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6); it is essentially identical to the CodeAcademy version with minor bug fixes.

For an interactive shell, I recommend Dreampie (http://www.dreampie.org/download.html); it has decent live code editing with code completion and documentation.

I also use the Notepad++ text editor (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.5.5.html) quite a bit; it has decent code formatting and coloring (although the Python indentation is broken out-of-the-box; you have to go into Settings / Preferences..., Tab Settings, Python, uncheck Use default value, and check Replace by space to make it PEP-8 compliant). There is also a plugin, PyNPP, which will let you launch Python code directly from NotePad++ (no more cut-and-paste!) - you can get it through Notepad++'s built-in Plugin Manager - then hit Alt-Shift-F5 to launch the current file in an interactive Python shell window.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
print sys.version_info
# sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

so you are looking for the 2.7.3 version from python.org

If you are very new to python, you may be experiencing the differences between python2 and python3. One main difference that a beginner will run into

```
print "this works" # in python 2
print("this works") # in python 3
```

print becomes a method, rather than whatever it was before... Also division is floating type by default, to get integer division in python 3 use `4//3 # output: 1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the interactive prompt, and a text editor.

If you want the interactive `Python` prompt:

1. If you are on Windows, look for a directory called `C:\Python?` and find a `bin\python.exe`.
2. If you are on Linux or OSX, typing `python` in the Terminal should get you the interactive prompt.

For a text editor to define functions, `Notepad` or `gedit` should help you.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to write a Python program, I open Windows explorer and go to the directory where I keep my .py files.  When I right click a .py file, I am given the choice to "Edit with IDLE."  I like IDLE really well.  When I "Run" a program a Python Shell window opens.  I work between these two windows.

(I think I used Notepad to create the first .py file because if you open IDLE you get a Python Shell.)  (Another oddity - when I want to create a new program file I "Save As" to a new name.)  In spite of these oddities IDLE is my favorite programming environment.

Answer (score 0):

Like I suspect most people reading this, I have no experience with Codecademy, but they seem to be running their own web front-end http://repl.it/ which is available for download -- if you really wanted to (and had the skills to set up a web server to host it on) you could even run that yourself.

The user interface looks like your run-of-the-mill programmers' editor; the abysmal color scheme is probably not worth copying anyway, and the interactive evaluation of your code (rather than the traditional save, quit, run, repeat cycle) is available via plug-ins in many modern editors. Or, as others have already suggested, you could use [IDLE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html), which is a part of the standard Python distribution.

If Python's default interactive mode feels clumsy but otherwise right, you might also want to look at a popular souped-up replacement [iPython](http://ipython.org/)

Comment: Of course, real men use Emacs (and their sysadmin baby sisters run `vi`) but that will require a Codecademy of its own before you start to see the payoffs.

Answer (score 0):

I think Komodo Edit is the editor codeacademy used to teach us.